# Why will my tests run fine in a browser, but not in Docker?

Tags: c#, docker, selenium-webdriver, automation, frameworks

I'm sorry if this is vague or if posting full classes isn't acceptable. However, I'm building a framework for work and running into issues when it comes to Docker.

I had it working fine but decided to separate my `Driver.cs` into 2 classes, with one for settings. Since then I just can't get my tests to run remotely, even though they work fine otherwise. I have the nodes up and running (like I said I had it working before) so not sure what else it could be. I also need advice on the part that uses a list as it's confusing me a bit.

WebDriverSettings.cs:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace WillAdamsonAutomationFramework.MyDrivers
{
public class WebDriverSettings
{
    public string DefaultBrowser = "chrome"; // Set to `all` to run tests in all browsers simultaneously
    public bool DefaultHeadless = false;
    public bool DefaultRemote = true; // Set to `false` to run tests in Browser, or `true` to run tests in Docker
    public IWebDriver driver;

    public IReadOnlyList<IWebDriver> CreateDrivers()
    {
        string browser = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEST_BROWSER") ?? DefaultBrowser;
        bool headless = bool.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HEADLESS") ?? DefaultHeadless.ToString());
        bool remote = bool.Parse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("REMOTE") ?? DefaultRemote.ToString());

        var drivers = new List<IWebDriver>();

        switch (browser.ToLower())
        {
            case "chrome":
                drivers.Add(CreateChromeDriver(headless, remote));
                break;
            case "edge":
                drivers.Add(CreateEdgeDriver(headless, remote));
                break;
            case "firefox":
                drivers.Add(CreateFirefoxDriver(headless, remote));
                break;
            case "all":
                drivers.Add(CreateChromeDriver(headless, remote));
                drivers.Add(CreateEdgeDriver(headless, remote));
                drivers.Add(CreateFirefoxDriver(headless, remote));
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException($"Unsupported browser: {browser}");
        }

        return drivers.AsReadOnly();
    }

    private IWebDriver CreateChromeDriver(bool headless, bool remote)
    {
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        if (headless)
        {
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
        }

        if (remote)
        {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/"), chromeOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        }

        return driver;
    }

    private IWebDriver CreateEdgeDriver(bool headless, bool remote)
    {
        EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
        if (headless)
        {
            edgeOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
        }

        if (remote)
        {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/"), edgeOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            driver = new EdgeDriver(edgeOptions);
        }

        return driver;
    }

    private IWebDriver CreateFirefoxDriver(bool headless, bool remote)
    {
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        if (headless)
        {
            firefoxOptions.AddArguments("--headless");
        }

        if (remote)
        {
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/"), firefoxOptions);
        }
        else
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        }

        return driver;
    }
}
}
```

Driver.cs:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
using BoDi;
using AventStack.ExtentReports;
using AventStack.ExtentReports.Reporter;

namespace WillAdamsonAutomationFramework.MyDrivers
{
[Binding]
public class Driver
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer container;
    private ExtentReports extent;
    private ExtentTest test;
    private bool isTestFailed;

    public static string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    public string reportDirectory = dir.Replace("bin\\Debug\\net7.0", "TestResults");

    public Driver(IObjectContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;

        string screenshotsPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "screenshots");
        if (!Directory.Exists(screenshotsPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotsPath);
        }

        ExtentSparkReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentSparkReporter(reportDirectory + "index.html");
        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.AttachReporter(htmlReporter);
    }

    [BeforeScenario]
    public void CreateDriver(WebDriverSettings webDriverSettings)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<IWebDriver> drivers = webDriverSettings.CreateDrivers();

        var driver = drivers[0];

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.saucedemo.com/");

        container.RegisterInstanceAs(driver);

        test = extent.CreateTest($"Scenario: {ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title}");
    }

    [AfterScenario]
    public void DestroyDriver()
    {
        var driver = container.Resolve<IWebDriver>();
        if (isTestFailed)
        {
            test.Fail("Scenario Failed");
        }
        else
        {
            test.Pass("Scenario Passed");
        }

        driver.Quit();
        driver.Dispose();
        extent.Flush();
    }
}
}
```

Error when running remotely:

```
    LogInToStandardUser
       Source: Scenario1.feature line 9
       Duration: 663 ms

      Message: 
    System.InvalidOperationException : Could not start a new session. Error while creating session with the driver service. Stopping driver service: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
    Host info: host: 'aa75cf455176', ip: '172.17.0.2'
    Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
    System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.21'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
    System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '11.0.21'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown (SessionNotCreated)
    TearDown : BoDi.ObjectContainerException : Interface cannot be resolved: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebDriver

      Stack Trace: 
    WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
    WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
    WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities capabilities)
    WebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
    RemoteWebDriver.ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities capabilities)
    RemoteWebDriver.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities capabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
    RemoteWebDriver.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities capabilities)
    RemoteWebDriver.ctor(Uri remoteAddress, DriverOptions options)
    WebDriverSettings.CreateChromeDriver(Boolean headless, Boolean remote) line 57
    WebDriverSettings.CreateDrivers() line 27
    <22 more frames...>
   Driver.DestroyDriver() line 52
    RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
    MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
    TestExecutionEngine.FireEvents(HookType hookType)
    TestExecutionEngine.FireScenarioEvents(HookType bindingEvent)
    TestExecutionEngine.OnScenarioEnd()
    TestRunner.OnScenarioEnd()
    Scenario1Feature.TestTearDown()
    RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
    MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)

      Standard Output: 
    Given I log in with username standard_user
    -> skipped because of previous errors
    Given I log in with password secret_sauce
    -> skipped because of previous errors
    When I see the inventory page
    -> skipped because of previous errors
    And I add Sauce Labs Fleece Jacket to my cart
    -> skipped because of previous errors
    And I checkout with the following customer information:
      --- table step argument ---
      | First Name | Last Name | Postal Code |
      | Standard   | User      | PR7 6TE     |
    -> skipped because of previous errors
    Then Checkout: Complete! is displayed
    -> skipped because of previous errors

      (result has additional output)

       Open test log
```

Tried deleting and remaking the nodes in Docker, and changing the code in various ways. Expected the tests to run fine remotely but the tests are failing and not being picked up at localhost.

Comment: Sorry for how the error message came out I got confused with the formatting/indenting! Hope it still makes sense